# update variable in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

The problem is that in he callback I tried to set `article.color`, but if I add `console.log(article.color)` after `color` it is still #FF0000 (inside `color` it detect dominant colors and work perfectly).

How update variable inside callback?

```js
var articles = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync( 'src/articles/articles.json' , 'utf8') );
var totalArticles = articles.length;
var readyArticles = 0;

function testReady(){
    readyArticles++;
    if(readyArticles == totalArticles){
        fs.writeFile('src/articles/articles.build.json', JSON.stringify(articles));
    }
}

articles.forEach(function( article ) {
    var imgPath = './src/'+article.background;
    article.color = '#FF0000';

    color( imgPath , function(err, color) {
        if( !err ){
            article.color = color;
        } else {
            console.log( err, color );
        }
    });

    testReady()
});
```

Comment: Your callback is called asynchronously. The order of execution is: 1) The code before the `color(...)` call is run. 2) `color(...)` is called which initiates an action which is to be completed later. 3) The code after `color(...)` runs, so of course `article.color` won't have changed. 4) Some time later, when the action initiated by the `color(...)` call finished, your callback runs. So, you would have to move all code which originally came *after* your `color(...)` call *into the callback* as well. And if you have a dependency to outside code, you would need to add a callback of your own, etc

Comment: @CherryDT I can add `fs.writeFile('src/articles/articles.build.json', JSON.stringify(articles));` inside `color`, but it will overwrite json in each loop. I think there is a better solution

Comment: OK I see only now that you have a loop around it as well. In this case you would need to have a counter which you increase by one every time `color`'s callback is run, and when it reaches `articles.length` (which you better save into a variable before), you call `testReady`. The more elegant way to do it would be promises, though.

Answer (score 0):

by tip @CherryDT working solution is:

```js
var articles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('src/articles/articles.json', 'utf8'));
var totalArticles = articles.length;
var readyArticles = 0;

function testReady() {
  readyArticles++;
  if (readyArticles == totalArticles) {
    console.log('Add ' + readyArticles + ' colors');
    fs.writeFile('src/articles/articles.build.json', JSON.stringify(articles));
  }
}

articles.forEach(function(article) {
  article.color = '#FF0000';

  color('./src/' + article.background, function(err, color) {
    if (!err) {
      article.color = '#' + color;
    } else {
      console.log(err, color);
    }

    testReady();
  })
});
```